# (Function) Verificação de campos preenchidos retornar ação anterior

Tags: javascript, html, funções, validação

Tenho uma função que verifica se os campos do meu formulário foram preenchidos ou não pegando pelo seu valor.

Caso tenha sido preenchido determinados campos e executado uma ação em que aparece a **progressBar**.

Nesta função tenho **4 Ifs** que fazem a verificação e vai acrescentando mais um numero de campos para ver se foi preenchido ou não e então exibe a progressBar correspondente.

O problema é se todo o formulário foi preenchido ativando o quarto If e exibindo a "**progressBar100**", se depois disso o valor do campo "**verInq1**" for excluído a barra que passa a ser exibida no lugar da "**progressBar100**" será a "**progressBar0**" ao invés de ser a "**progressBar75**". Isso acontece em todos os Ifs.

Então eu queria fazer a verificação ao contrário também, em ordem decrescente onde se o último If não foi validado então ele retornasse o terceiro If e assim por diante.

HTML das progressBar.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
    <div id="InqProgress0" class="progress barProgressAbas">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="InqProgress25" class="progress barProgressAbas ocultaProgressAbas">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
    </div>
    <div id="InqProgress50" class="progress barProgressAbas ocultaProgressAbas">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">50%</div>
    </div>
    <div id="InqProgress75" class="progress barProgressAbas ocultaProgressAbas">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">75%</div>
    </div>
    <div id="InqProgress100" class="progress barProgressAbas ocultaProgressAbas">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">100%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Meu JS para checar o valor e executar ação.

```
function progressBarInq() {
            let progressBar0 = document.getElementById("InqProgress0");
            let progressBar25 = document.getElementById("InqProgress25");
            let progressBar50 = document.getElementById("InqProgress50");
            let progressBar75 = document.getElementById("InqProgress75");
            let progressBar100 = document.getElementById("InqProgress100");

            //25%
            let verInq1 = document.getElementById("InqueritoCircunscricaoPolicial");            
            //50%
            let verInq5 = document.getElementById("NumeroDoIP");            
            //75%
            let verInq8 = document.getElementById("DataDoRelatorio");                          
            //100%
            let verInq11 = document.getElementById("NumeroDoProcesso");                        

            if (verInq1.value) {
                progressBar0.style.display = "none";
                progressBar25.style.display = "block";
                progressBar50.style.display = "none";
                progressBar75.style.display = "none";
                progressBar100.style.display = "none";
            } 
            if (verInq1.value && verInq5.value) {
                progressBar0.style.display = "none";
                progressBar25.style.display = "none";
                progressBar50.style.display = "block";
                progressBar75.style.display = "none";
                progressBar100.style.display = "none";
            } 
            if (verInq1.value && verInq5.value && verInq8.value) {
                progressBar0.style.display = "none";
                progressBar25.style.display = "none";
                progressBar50.style.display = "none";
                progressBar75.style.display = "block";
                progressBar100.style.display = "none";
            } 
            if (verInq1.value && verInq5.value && verInq8.value && verInq11.value) {
                progressBar0.style.display = "none";
                progressBar25.style.display = "none";
                progressBar50.style.display = "none";
                progressBar75.style.display = "none";
                progressBar100.style.display = "block";
            } 

        }    

        progressBarInq();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode simplificar esses selects...
Além disso da pra simplificar o html para que possamos manipular somente o width ao inves de display...
Sendo assim da pra ter somente um progressbar.

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
    <div id="InqProgress0" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
// selecionado o progress bar 
var progress = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');

//suas variaveis
let verInq1 = document.getElementById("InqueritoCircunscricaoPolicial");            
let verInq5 = document.getElementById("NumeroDoIP");            
let verInq8 = document.getElementById("DataDoRelatorio");                          
let verInq11 = document.getElementById("NumeroDoProcesso");

//aqui temos a definição em valor do width
//traduzindo temos ->
// total = (tem verInq1? então ja vale 25) + (tem verInq5? então soma 25)..etc..
let total = (verInq1 ? 25 : 0) +  (verInq5 ? 25 : 0) + (verInq8 ? 25 : 0) + (verInq11 ? 25 : 0);
//são expressões ternárias, vale a pena estudar.

//e aqui temos nosso width sendo setado com template string
progress.style.width = `${total}%`;
```

Comment: e como ficaria a verificação dos IFs?